# How to Replicate data between a hosted database and a local database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, linked-server

I have a Cloud hosted Database, maintained by a different company.  Here is my scenario:

- Cloud Hosted Database SQL Server 2012 - Need to connect through a VPN.
- We setup a local Server with with Dual NIC cards.  This allows us to have the    VPN connection, and the local network connection.
- I would like to have a local copy of the cloud hosted database on our server.
- I cannot setup replication inside SQL server, I do not have permissions on the cloud server.
- I cannot do a back-up and restore of the database - I do not have permissions on the cloud server.
- I cannot use triggers
- I cannot use logs.
- I cannot use back-ups

How can I bring down the entire database, schema and data, and keep my Local database updated real-time?

*Edit:  I was able to get a script run from the hosting company so I could create the database along with the schema and initial data.*

The most important question is how can I keep the data synchronized real-time?  Right now, i'm thinking of doing a series of Jobs in SQL to query the Linked Server database with something like this:

```
insert into local_table_1
select * from linkedserver_table1
except
select * from local_table_1
```

The problem is, it's not efficient, and it will not pull any of the updated records.  We do have an "Updated_date" field.  How can I update the local server, selecting all records from the Linked server, and update the local database?

Comment: Is your hosted database not already taking full and log backups? You should be able to shimmy your own log shipping based on that, or periodic restores based on the fulls at least.

Comment: The hosted database was created and maintained by another company (Franchise).  As the Franchisee, they give us access to the DB to run Queries, and not much else.

Comment: Well if your local SQL Server can have a linked server to the hosted database, you can use [a solution like this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/128614/1186). But you should tell Franchise what you plan to do and why, and advise them that it will put strain on their server. Maybe then they'd consider allowing you to have a copy of the backups (which, hopefully, they're already taking anyway). That is a much more straightforward solution - better for you, and better for them.

Comment: If you can use SSIS, then you can do [incremental load](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/114214/8783) and schedule your package through SQL Agent Job.

Comment: I don't think you can use SSIS for Linked Servers, can you?

Comment: Any way we can put something *in front* of your app prior to the database, such as application level firewall/reverse proxy?

Comment: I thought about that, but i'm not sure how I could get something like that to work.  Not to mention they offload the data after 1 year, so i'm without data after 12 months.  It'd be much better for me to be able to pull all data to a local server, and keep a running, local server here I can manage.

Comment: With the constraints you are working around any solution is going to be inefficient really. I would do what Kin has already suggested, create a custom SSIS package and let it run on a schedule to keep everything in sync.

Comment: Agree with @Kin with your set of limitations your best bet is going to be SSIS. However I will say that A: the dev cost on this will not be cheap depending how many tables you have. B: You'll have to account for schema changes. C: It **won't** be real time. D: there **will** be load costs on both servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no replication or out-of-the-box solution to your problem, particularly since you don't have that type of access to the remote machine. As other commenters here have noted, you're probably going to have to build your own ETL logic, perhaps in one of the following ways:

- A linked server and stored procedures using `OPENQUERY()` or `OPENROWSET()`,
- An SSIS package, or
- A custom-built local application.

The "last updated" columns in the remote tables will help you considerably, in that you won't have to download the entire database's contents every time you run the ETL process. Without being able to install or modify anything on the remote server, there's no practical way to synchronize in "real time". The frequency and speed that you can synchronize the databases will probably come down to:

- Indexing on the remote database (how efficiently you can retrieve new records)
- Workload on the remote server (locks, I/O speed, available CPU)
- Link speed (how fast your VPN is)

I would set a reasonable expectation of synchronizing the data a few times per day, for example early morning, lunch, late afternoon and/or evening. Make sure to plan those executions so they don't collide unneccessarily with running backup jobs (locally, and if you can, remote). Involve the remote party so you don't overload their servers.

**T-SQL example**

Supposing that you use stored procedures and linked servers, here's an idea on how to go about it. First off, if existing data *never changes*, i.e. rows are only added (say, like accounting transactions or something):

```
DECLARE @lastUpdated   datetime2(3),
        @sql           varchar(max);

--- What's the most recent row we've downloaded?
SELECT @lastUpdated=MAX(lastUpdated)
FROM dbo.tableName;

--- Build dynamic SQL
SET @sql='
    INSERT INTO dbo.tableName (x, y, z, lastUpdated)
    SELECT x, y, z, lastUpdated
    FROM OPENQUERY(linkedServerName, ''
        SELECT x, y, z, lastUpdated
        FROM databaseName.dbo.tableName
        WHERE lastUpdated>={ts '''''+CONVERT(varchar, @lastUpdated, 121)+'''''}
        '');
    ';

--- Execute dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

... and repeat this process for each table. You may run into problems with foreign key constraints, so you may have to arrange the order of the tables carefully, but in the end you may be better off not having any foreign key constraints at all in the local database.

If your existing rows can change, the SQL script looks similar, except you download the data to a temp table first, assign a unique clustered primary key to the temp table, then [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) ("upsert") the contents of the temp table to your local table. If you don't like or trust `MERGE`, you can obviously use `INSERT` and `UPDATE` the old fashion way. Note that you won't catch rows that have been *deleted* from the remote table this way.

**Using SSIS**

With SSIS (or if you decide to build your own local application), the work is the same, but you won't need linked servers, and instead of using `sp_executesql`, you'll dynamically build SQL statements and run them through an ADODB or similar database connection.

I've included the "build your own application" option for completeness; I wouldn't go down that road.

**Indexing considerations**

For the remote query to be as efficient as possible, you may want to investigate if you can get the remote DBA to set up an index on the "last updated" column of each table.

**Backup option**

In the end, I would probably consider Aaron Bertrand's suggestion and try to set up a solution where you download a backup of the remote database (perhaps a full backup, once per night), restore that backup locally and perform the sync operation locally on your server.

**Real-time**

Returning to the real-time issue - the driving parameter here has to be the business. If management needs up-to-the-second accuracy in your database, somebody is going to have to accept the considerable increase in work and costs, not to mention maintenance. In the end, you may find that a high-speed leased line may be a lot cheaper, and that you can archive the data with a giant download once a month or so instead.